# Typescript use optional generic

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```
function prop<T extends Record<any, any>, K extends keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
   
}

const v = prop<{ test: string }>('test')
```

The issue is that I must pass a second generic to correctly infer the key. Is there any way to skip the second generic and still infer the `key` as `keyof T`?

I don't want to do the following:

```
prop<{ test: string }, 'test'>('test')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use default generic like this one:

```
function prop<T extends Record<any, any>, K = keyof T>(key: K): T[K] {
   
}

const v1 = prop<{ test: string }>('test') // OK
const v2 = prop<{ test: string }>('test12') // ERROR
```